# Loud ticking engine noise

Tags: engine, ford, noise, fiesta

I own a 2005 ford fiesta st150, and I'm currently facing an issue where my engine makes a repetitive ticking noise over 2000 RPM.
The noise is a very periodic ticking that seems to follow engine speed, it's present during up revving, steady revving and down revving, when I disconnect any spark plug or injector, it's still there.

I changed the accessory belt and all the accessories (excepted alternator but the noise is there even without the belt), I replaced the timing chain, pulleys, tensioners... I replaced the camshafts, the exhaust system and the inlet manifold, I checked the mechanical cam followers adjustment, inlet is between 0.20mm and 0.25mm, and exhaust is between 0.25mm and 0.35mm.
Today I disassembled the timing chain again to see if I did something wrong, but it seems perfectly fitted.

Any suggestions will be welcome

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

I tried hunting down the noise with a stethoscope and didn't manage to find where it came from. The overall noise seems to come from the exhaust side of the engine, timing chain side, maybe more from the bottom end than from the head but not sure of that.

Comment: Is it loud clattering as in the title or is it repetitive ticking as in the question? Please click Edit and make it one or the other so we know what we're dealing with.

Comment: Edited, thanks for your comment

Answer (score 2):

Before you replace any more parts, buy an inexpensive oil pressure test kit. It's a hand-held pressure gauge with an assortment of fittings, one of which should fit the port for the oil pressure sending unit, or in some cases an actual test port near the oil filter.

The lack of an oil pressure warning light only means that the oil pressure is at least 4 psi or thereabouts. You should check and see what the pressure really is at various rpm and temperature conditions and take it from there.

Low oil pressure should be a first thought for a persistent ticking sound that follows engine speed.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'll buy one as soon as possible

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for trusting us with your issue! What I do when I'm tracking an odd sound is use a stethoscope. Automotive stethoscopes are super cheap(I paid $3 for mine) and come with a handy solid metal probe. Simply create the conditions needed to make the sound and poke it around until you hear the ticking the loudest. Don't necessarily stop when you first hear the sound through the 'scope! Poke around and make sure that this is THE loudest anywhere. No matter how unlikely, this is where the problem lies.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to tell that I got a stehoscope, and hunting down the didn't help me find it's source this time, I cannot pinpoint the exact origin of it, but it seemsvto come from tge exhaust side, timing chain side, maybe bottom end side but not sure, whatever thanks for your suggestion